# Symfony custom repository query giving error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am really new at Symfony and I am trying to get used to query builder. At the moment I am trying to join three tables and the following MySQL query gives me the results I need when I run it in PhpMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM pe_users u
LEFT JOIN pe_apply a ON u.id = a.user
LEFT JOIN pe_offer o ON a.id = o.application
```

However when I move this inside a Symfony Repository method

```
namespace Ache\AdminBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class AdminRepository extends EntityRepository{
    public function findAllAppByStatus(){
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT * FROM pe_users u
             LEFT JOIN pe_apply a ON u.id = a.user
             LEFT JOIN pe_offer o ON a.id = o.application
             ');
        try {
            return $query->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable |
>   ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '*'

What does this error mean? what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The three entities I have are as following

```
UserBundle:User
CoreBundle:Apply
AdminBundle:Offer
```

`User.id` links with `Apply.user` and `Offer.application` links with `Apply.id`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `createQuery()` is for creating DQL queries - where it looks you are creating a raw SQL, or perhaps a hybrid raw/DQL query. For instance a DQL query might look like this: `SELECT u FROM FooBundle:User u Join u.offer o` etc.

Comment: @Darragh well Symfony documentaion seems to be using it http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-related-records

Comment: Not exactly. The main problem with your query is Doctrine DQL does not support the  `*` glob. @DonCallisto includes this in his answer below. More information on DQL queries here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: I've deleted my answer as, at the moment, I can't correct it and I need to take a deep look to this question because I'm afraid that I've didn't understood it. BTW you cannot use `*` in DQL, you must use `BundleName:EntityName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use raw sql with Symfony if you are comfortable with that

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pe_users u LEFT JOIN pe_apply a ON u.id = a.user LEFT JOIN pe_offer o ON a.id = o.application WHERE u.id = a.user";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
public function findAllAppByStatus(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->leftJoin('CoreBundle:Apply', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.user = u')
    ->leftJoin('AdminBundle:Offer', 'o', 'WITH', 'o.application = a')
    ->setMaxResults(1); // if you return only 1 result, you want to be sure only one (or none) result is fetched

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

if you want to return possibly many results, as the 'All' in the method name suggests, get rid of the `->setMaxResults()` and use `$qb->getQuery()->getResult();`

see how the queryBuilder works with objects, not tables. Joins are built on entities and properties, not tables and field names.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need and did work by the way. However the scenario is that even if the user data does not exist in `AdminBundle:Offer` I still need the user to be listed. So on the front end the data will be displayed where the user has provided it, where the user did not provide the user null will be displayed. ofcourse i will handle the front end, its just the query that i am struggling with to pull the records. So how can i change your query to achieve the above?

Comment: What are you trying to fetch ? A list of users with their (optional) related offer, or a list of offers with their (optional) related user ?